# How to confirm something in Linux command-line prompt

Tags: command-line, curl, ovh

In order to install Composer on my OVH web hosting service, I need to pass some SSH commands.

To pass them, OVH wants me to install some CLI using commands (guide [here](https://docs.ovh.com/ie/en/web-paas/development-cli/#installation))

> To connect using certificate-based authentication, install the Web PaaS CLI.

PaaS CLI is supposedly installed with this command.

> ### Objective
>
> The CLI is the official tool to use and manage your Web PaaS projects directly from your terminal. Anything you can do within the management console can be done with the CLI.
>
> Behinds the scenes it uses both the Git interface and our REST API. The source code of the CLI is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/ovh/webpaas-cli).
>
> ### Installation
>
> You can install the CLI easily using this command
>
> ```
> curl -fsS https: //eu.cli.webpaas.ovhcloud.com/installer | php
> ```
>
> You can find the system requirements and more information in the [installation instructions on GitHub](https://github.com/ovh/webpaas-cli/blob/master/README.md#installation).

The command doesn't work on the Windows Terminal.

```
        }
        
        return $selected;
   }
}
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: php.exe

C:\Users\Alex>curl -sfS https://eu.cli.webpaas.ovhcloud.com/installer | apt install php7.2-cli
'apt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\Users\Alex>ssh Alex@Alex-PC
ssh: connect to host Alex-PC port 22: Connection refused
```

So I tried from the Linux prompt from my Hive OS mining machine. Attempting the installation command from my mining machine:

```
root@Dual_RTX_3090:/# curl -sfS https://eu.cli.webpaas.ovhcloud.com/installer | php

Command ‘php’ not found, but can be installed with:

apt install php7.2-cli
apt install hhvm

curl: (23) Failed writing body (539 != 5935)
root@Dual_RTX 3090: /# curl -sfS https://eu.cli.webpaas.ovhcloud.com/installer | apt install php7.2-cli
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libsodium23 php-common php7.2-common php7.2-json php7.2-opcache php7.2-readline
suggested packages :
  php-pear
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libsodium23 php-common php7.2-cli php7.2-common php7.2-json php7.2-opcache php7.2-readline
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
Need to get 2647 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
root@Dual_RTX_3090:/# Y
Y: command not found
root@Dual_RTX_3090:/#
```

So I pasted

```
curl -sfS https://eu.cli.webpaas.ovhcloud.com/installer | php
```

in the Command prompt, and I got served with

> Command 'php' not nound, but can be installed with ...

so I then tried

```
curl -sfS https://eu.cli.webpaas.ovhcloud.com/installer | apt install php7.2-cli
```

and from there, it asked me to confirm.

> Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.

I tried to type "Y" and enter, but that doesn't do it.

How do you confirm this at this point?

Comment: I think you can install php first by `apt install php7.2-cli` and then execute the `curl` command.

Answer (score 1):

Using `apt install php7.2-cli` and then `curl` did it; thanks to [z.h.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/254697/z-h) for their comment!

```
root@Dual_RTX_3090:/# curl -sfS https://eu.cli.webpaas.ovhcloud.com/installer | php
OVHcloud Web PaaS CLI installer

Environment check
  [*] The "json" PHP extension is installed.
  [*] The "phar" PHP extension is installed.
  [*] Git is installed.
  [*] The "openssl" PHP extension is installed.
  [*] The "pcre" PHP extension is installed.
  [*] One or both of the "mbstring" or "iconv" PHP extensions is installed.
  [!] The "curl" PHP extension is strongly recommended.
  [*] The "pcntl" and "posix" extensions are installed.
  [*] The "allow_url_fopen" setting is on.
  [*] The "apc.enable_cli" setting is off.

Download
  Finding the latest version... done
  Downloading version 3.70.1... done
  Checking file integrity... done
  Checking that the file is a valid Phar... done

Install
  Making the Phar executable... done
  Moving the Phar to your home directory... done
  Executable location: /home/user/.webpaas-cli/bin/webpaas

Running self:install command...

Copying resource files... done

Setting up autocompletion... done

Selected shell configuration file: ~/.bashrc

Do you want to update the file automatically? [Y/n] y

Configuration file updated successfully: ~/.bashrc

To use the OVHcloud Web PaaS CLI, run:
    source ~/.bashrc # (make sure your shell does this by default)
    webpaas
root@Dual_RTX_3090:/#
```

Let's see if I can now pass the SSH commands to OVH to get that Composer installed.